# GTK 2.22 with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, gtk

I'm trying to compile a VS 2010 project that uses GTK2.22. I added the all-in-one packages, include paths and libraries but there is still over a thousands errors.

As an example, here are a few of them:

gdkcolor.h:

```
struct _GdkColormap
{
  GObject parent_instance;

  gint      GSEAL (size);
  GdkColor *GSEAL (colors);    
  GdkVisual *GSEAL (visual);      
  gpointer GSEAL (windowing_data);
};
```

error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'size' 'colors' 'visual' and 'windowing_data'

My guess is that some OS related dependency is missing but I have no idea which one. Anyone has an idea what could it be?

Comment: Look for the **first** error you get from the compiler, which will likely be about a missing include. That is what you need to fix before looking into the rest of them.

Comment: Also, gtk 2.22 is not the latest of GTK2. You probably want the latest from the 2.24 series, currently 2.24.17.